# Graphics.DrawString: count the number of characters fully displayed in rectangle efficiently

Tags: .net, winforms, gdi+, clip, drawstring

I'm using custom drawing to draw a string in a WinForms application. The classic [Graphics.DrawString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21kdfbzs(v=vs.110).aspx) method is used for that:

```
g.DrawString(text, font, brush, rect, stringFormat);
```

The output string `text` can be clipped by the rectangle `rect`, and I need to count the number of characters fully visible in `rect`. How to do that using the .NET Framework built-in tools?

Please, don't suggest using other methods to output text. I need to solve this task for GDI+ Graphics.DrawString.

---

UPDATE: Yes, sure, I can use [Graphics.MeasureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb(v=vs.110).aspx) in a loop in which I sum the width of every character from the beginning of the string, but I need something more efficient like the `DT_MODIFYSTRING` flag in the WinAPI [DrawText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Add to this that `Graphics.MeasureString` does not calculate the required width properly. Fore more info, see this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2118/Bypass-Graphics-MeasureString-limitations

Comment: Are you familiar with Graphics.MeasureString? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Biscuits, are you familiar with the problems related to Graphics.MeasureString? See, for instance, [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2118/Bypass-Graphics-MeasureString-limitations). It seems, we need to use [StringFormat.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformat.setmeasurablecharacterranges(v=vs.110).aspx) for more precise calculations.

Answer (score -1):

You are going to have to loop, character by character, through the string, measuring each one using `Graphics.MeasureString` until it goes beyond the rectangle, then back off by one character.

It becomes more complex if it's a multi-line textbox, because then you have to figure out proper word breaks.  You may end up backing off multiple characters if you break on whole words.

Comment: You could do that.  Or use the MeasureString overload that has the *charactersFitted* argument, that's a lot easier.  No point in mentioning textbox btw, it doesn't use DrawString.

Comment: Well sure, if you want to do it the easy way... (I wasn't aware of that overload, thanks!)

Comment: This is not efficient. I've updated my question, read the UPDATE section.

Comment: @HansPassant, it seems, the overloaded version of [MeasureString with charactersFitted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/957webty(v=vs.110).aspx) could be the answer to my question - though the calculation is still not "quite correct" as MeasureString adds some extra pixels to the result. What can you say about using StringFormat.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges in a loop? Is it a precise solution?